# Why wont this WMI script read my registry string value?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I'm using the examples from technet to try to read a dword / string from HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run called MyStartupExe.. It is returning empty.. This regular example works:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject( _
   "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Console"
strValueName = "HistoryBufferSize"
oReg.GetDWORDValue _
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
WScript.Echo "Current History Buffer Size: " & dwValue
```

My adaptation of it does not work. The string and dword value exists in the registry at the key path I'm looking for.

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject( _
   "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
strValueName = "MyStartUpExe"
oReg.GetDWORDValue _
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
WScript.Echo "MyStartupExe" & dwValue
```

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?

Comment: what's the error or value you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MyStartUpExe" is most likely a `REG_SZ` value, not a `REG_DWORD` value, so you'll have to use `GetStringValue()` instead of `GetDWORDValue()`.

```
oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, value
WScript.Echo "MyStartUpExe" & value
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [WMI StdRegProv class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393664(v=vs.85).aspx).

Or you could just use `Shell.RegRead` to read registry values where you don't know the values' datatype. If the return code of `RegRead` is 0 (success) a reg value exists, else if the return code will be some general error code, e.g. `&h800xxxxx` etc. then no reg value exists. To check your OS architecture type, query the `Win32_Processor.Architecture` value (where '0' = 'x86' or '9' = 'x64').